# Getting error message when using 'np.where'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined a function that should add a new column called *season* to the data frame. The values of season are extracted from the *date* column:

```py
def season(df):

    df['sum'] = ((df['date'].dt.month) * 100) + df['date'].dt.day

    df['season'] = np.where(df['sum'] > 320 & df['sum'] < 621, 1, np.where(df['sum'] > 620 & df['sum'] < 923, 2, np.where(df['sum'] > 922 & df['sum'] < 1223, 3, 4)))

    df.drop(['sum'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    return df
```

But when I call this function inside the main code, I get this error message:
`The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Where should be modified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `df['sum'] >320` inside brackets, i.e. `(df['sum']>320)&(...)`.

Or you can use `gt` and `lt`: `df['sum'].gt(320)`